# How do I verify in WatiN that a <ul> contains certain links

Tags: watin

Let's say we have the following list in an HTML document:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Page">Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I verify with WatiN that "menu" contains exactly those hyperlinks, in a concise manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution, it was the best I could think of:

```
private static void CheckMenu(string title)
{
    Browser browser = WebBrowser.Current;

    // Verify menu
    WatiN.Core.List menu = browser.List("menu");
    var links = menu.OwnListItems.Select(item => item.Links[0]).ToList();
    Assert.That(links.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
    CheckLink(links[0], "/", "Home");
    CheckLink(links[1], "/Page", "Page");
}

private static void CheckLink(Link link, string path, string text)
{
    // The href value is translated to an absolute URL, gah :/
    Assert.That(link.GetAttributeValue("href"), Is.StringMatching(
                string.Format("[^:]+://[^/]+{0}", path)));
    Assert.That(link.Text, Is.EqualTo(text));
}
```

Basically, I verify that there are two list items, and that they contain a link "Home" pointing to "/" and a link "Page" pointing to "/Page".

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the UL with id of menu, and then check its decendants to see if there are links which the links you're expecting.  It would be something along these lines (forgive me if I don't have the method names quite right).

```
var menuDiv = Browser.Current.Div(Find.ById("menu"));
Assert.That(menuDiv.Find.By("href", "/Page").Exists);
```

Comment: The first line works, but the second has at least a couple of problems. First of all, menuDiv has no method "Find"; this can be solved by calling menuDiv.Link with a suitable constraint. Your constraint Find.By("href", "/Page") doesn't work either though.

Comment: Right, I didn't have the API right in front of me.  You might need to specify the full Url, as it may have to match whatever is in hrf exactly.

Comment: Specifying the full URL doesn't make sense IMO, since the href actually contains a relative URL. Figuring out the full URL in the test code isn't necessarily that easy either. Maybe I should try regex...

Comment: Ok, I looked at the docs.  So maybe something like menuDiv.Links.Find(x=>x.Url.Contains("/Page")).  Using the Link type might make it easier to get what you need.